# Convert integer to binary array with suitable padding

Tags: python, numpy

I have integers in the range `0..2**m - 1` and I would like to convert them to binary numpy arrays of length `m`.  For example, say `m = 4`. Now `15 = 1111` in binary and so the output should be `(1,1,1,1)`.   `2 = 10` in binary and so the output should be `(0,0,1,0`).  If `m` were `3` then `2` should be converted to `(0,1,0)`.

I tried `np.unpackbits(np.uint8(num))` but that doesn't give an array of the right length. For example,

```
np.unpackbits(np.uint8(15))
Out[5]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint8)
```

I would like a method that worked for whatever `m` I have in the code.

Comment: Should `m` be inferred from the numbers in the array, or specified as an argument?

Comment: @amaurea Specified as an argument.

Comment: For anyone who found this on google trying to unpackbits for uint8's in-place in an array, I tried vectorizing and axis but neither worked. The solution is actually a lot simpler: `np.unpackbits(a).reshape(*a.shape,8)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to vectorize this, something like

```
>>> d = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> m = 8
>>> (((d[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(m)))) > 0).astype(int)
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

which just gets the appropriate bit weights and then takes the bitwise and:

```
>>> (1 << np.arange(m))
array([  1,   2,   4,   8,  16,  32,  64, 128])
>>> d[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(m))
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

There are lots of ways to convert this to 1s wherever it's non-zero `(> 0)*1`, `.astype(bool).astype(int)`, etc.  I chose one basically at random.

Comment: This is in reversed order.

Comment: `(((d[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(m))[::-1])) > 0).astype(int)` This gets the order right.

Answer (score 10):

One-line version, taking advantage of the fast path in `numpy.binary_repr`:

```
def bin_array(num, m):
    """Convert a positive integer num into an m-bit bit vector"""
    return np.array(list(np.binary_repr(num).zfill(m))).astype(np.int8)
```

Example:

```
In [1]: bin_array(15, 6)
Out[1]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int8)
```

Vectorized version for expanding an entire numpy array of ints at once:

```
def vec_bin_array(arr, m):
    """
    Arguments: 
    arr: Numpy array of positive integers
    m: Number of bits of each integer to retain

    Returns a copy of arr with every element replaced with a bit vector.
    Bits encoded as int8's.
    """
    to_str_func = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.binary_repr(x).zfill(m))
    strs = to_str_func(arr)
    ret = np.zeros(list(arr.shape) + [m], dtype=np.int8)
    for bit_ix in range(0, m):
        fetch_bit_func = np.vectorize(lambda x: x[bit_ix] == '1')
        ret[...,bit_ix] = fetch_bit_func(strs).astype("int8")

    return ret
```

Example:

```
In [1]: vec_bin_array(np.array([[100, 42], [2, 5]]), 8)

Out[1]: array([[[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]],

               [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]]], dtype=int8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a  code that converts a numpy integer array of any shape (i.e.: integer, vector, matrix..), to a numpy boolean array of the same shape + one more dimension that includes the bit elements of the integer in that location - and one can specify the bit depth of the conversion.

I think it is nice since it does all of that rather efficiently, and in a single line. Given integer input `int_input` to be converted to binary of depth `Nbits`:

```
binary_output = (np.bitwise_and(int_input.ravel()[:, None], np.array([2**i for i in np.arange(Nbits)[::-1]])) > 0).reshape(np.concatenate([np.asarray(int_input.shape), [Nbits]]))
```

**Example 1:** The vector `[0, 1, 3, 7, 115]` is converted using the line-code above to bit depth of 8 to :

```
[[False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False False  True  True]
 [False False False False False  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True False False  True  True]]
```

**Example 2:** More extensive, so we need to prepare the data: a matrix of 2,000 by 10,000 random integer elements, to be converted to bit depth of 16:

```
Nbits = 16
rng = np.random.default_rng()
int_input = np.floor(2**(Nbits-1)*np.asarray(rng.random([10**3, 10**4]))).astype("uint"+Nbits.__str__())
```

Will be converted using the line-code above to a numpy logical array with the shape of: `(2000, 10000, 16)`

Speed-wise, doing the above 20,000,000-element conversion 10 times using `timeit` takes a total of about 7.5 seconds

Finally, **Example 3:** in the case of really large datasets (relative to the computer's memory) the conversion takes up a lot of temporary memory. This can be alleviated if the conversion is done in smaller blocks. By defining BlkSz (e..g. `BlkSz = 1000`) along the first axis, the code-line is now:

```
binary_output = np.concatenate([(np.bitwise_and(int_input[b*BlkSz:np.min([(b+1)*BlkSz, int_input.shape[0]]), :].ravel()[:, None], np.array([2**i for i in np.arange(Nbits)[::-1]])) > 0).reshape(np.concatenate([np.asarray(int_input[b*BlkSz:np.min([(b+1)*BlkSz, int_input.shape[0]]), :].shape), [Nbits]])) for b in range(int_input.shape[0]//BlkSz+1)], axis=0)
```

Here `int_input` need to have >1 axes (which is normal for large datasets), but `BlkSz` can have any value - the length of first axis of the `int_input` need not be evenly divisible by `BlkSz`, or even smaller than that axis. Adding `BlkSz` (i.e. relative to the first line-code above) has no negative impact on performance, maybe even a small *positive* impact.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat 'hacky' solution.

```
def bin_array(num, m):
    """Returns an array representing the binary representation of num in m bits."""
    bytes = int(math.ceil(m / 8.0))
    num_arr = np.arange(num, num+1, dtype='>i%d' %(bytes))
    return np.unpackbits(num_arr.view(np.uint8))[-1*m:]
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to be able to specify m and for it to pad suitably.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could just modify the resulting array. I don't know the function exactly, but most implementations like `np.unpackbits` would not inherently know the size of the number - python ints can be arbitrarily large, after all, and don't have a native size.

However, if you know `m`, you can easily 'fix' the array. Basically, an unpack function will give you some number of bits (that is a multiple of 8) for the byte with the highest 1 in the number. You just need to remove extra 0s, or prepend 0s, to get the right distance:

```
m = 4
mval = np.unpackbits(np.uint8(15))

if len(mval) > m:
   mval = mval[m-len(mval):]
elif m > len(mval):
   # Create an extra array, and extend it
   mval = numpy.concatenate([numpy.array([0]*(m-len(mval)), dtype=uint8), mval])
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes m is specified as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

```py
m=24
tobin = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.array(list(np.binary_repr(x, m)), dtype=int), signature="()->({}})".format(m))

array = np.array([[10,10],[20,20]])
print(tobin(array))

"""
[[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]]]
shape: (2, 2, 24)
"""
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).