# numpy binary notation quick generation

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose, I have a `numpy` vector with `n` elements, so I'd like to encode numbers in this vector as a binary notation, so resulting shape will be `(n,m)` where `m`  is `log2(maxnumber)` for example:

```
x = numpy.array([32,5,67])
```

Because max number I have is `67`, I need `numpy.ceil(numpy.log2(67)) == 7` bits to encode this vector, so shape of the result will be `(3,7)`

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The problem rises because I have no quick way to move binary notation from
function `numpy.binary_repr` to numpy array. Now I have to iterate over result, and put each bit severally:

```
brepr = numpy.binary_repr(x[i],width=7)
j = 0
for bin in brepr:
   X[i][j] = bin
   j += 1
```

It's very timecost and stupid way, how to make it efficient?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227595/convert-integer-to-binary-array-with-suitable-padding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way using `np.unpackbits` and broadcasting:

```
>>> max_size = np.ceil(np.log2(x.max())).astype(int)
>>> np.unpackbits(x[:,None].astype(np.uint8), axis=1)[:,-max_size:]
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy byte string.

For the case you have in hand:

```
res = numpy.array(len(x),dtype='S7')
for i in range(len(x)):
    res[i] = numpy.binary_repr(x[i])
```

Or more compactly

```
res = numpy.array([numpy.binary_repr(val) for val in x])
```