# How to filter values using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Intention: To filter binary numbers based on hamming weights using pandas. Here i check number of 1s occurring in the binary and write the count to df.

Effort so far:

```
import pandas as pd
def ones(num):
    return bin(num).count('1')
num = list(range(1,8))
C = pd.Index(["num"])
df = pd.DataFrame(num, columns=C)
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda row : ones(row['num']), axis = 1)
print(df)
```

output:

```
   num  count
0    1      1
1    2      1
2    3      2
3    4      1
4    5      2
5    6      2
6    7      3


Intended output:
  1 2 3
0 1 3 7
1 2 5
2 4 6
```

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). Though you'll need to define the `index` as the `cumcount` of the grouped `count` column, `pivot_table` can't figure it out all on its own :)

```
(df.pivot_table(index=df.groupby('count').cumcount(), 
                columns='count', 
                values='num'))

count    1    2    3
0      1.0  3.0  7.0
1      2.0  5.0  NaN
2      4.0  6.0  NaN
```

You also have the parameter `fill_value`, though I wouldn't recommend you to use it, since you'll get mixed types. Now it looks like `NumPy` would be a good option from here, you can easily obtain an array from the result with `new_df.to_numpy()`.

---

Also, focusing on the logic in `ones`, we can vectorise this with (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22227898/9698684)):

```
m = df.num.to_numpy().itemsize
df['count'] = (df.num.to_numpy()[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(m)) > 0).view('i1').sum(1)
```

Here's a check on both approaches' performance:

```
df_large = pd.DataFrame({'num':np.random.randint(0,10,(10_000))})

def vect(df):
    m = df.num.to_numpy().itemsize
    (df.num.to_numpy()[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(m)) > 0).view('i1').sum(1)

%timeit vect(df_large)
# 340 µs ± 5.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df_large.apply(lambda row : ones(row['num']), axis = 1)
# 103 ms ± 2.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a different output:

```
df.groupby("count").agg(list)
```

which will give you

```
             num
count           
1      [1, 2, 4]
2      [3, 5, 6]
3            [7]
```

it's the same information in a slightly different format. In your original pivoted format, the rows are meaningless and you have an undetermined number of columns. I suggest it is more common to have an undetermined number of rows. I think you'll find this easier to work with going forward.

Or consider just creating a dictionary as a DataFrame is adding a lot of overhead here for no benefit:

```
df.groupby("count").agg(list).to_dict()["num"]
```

which gives you

```
{
    1: [1, 2, 4], 
    2: [3, 5, 6], 
    3: [7],
}
```

Comment: OP wants to group the numbers with the same numbers of `1`s in the binary representation. I don't think a pivot is the best data structure for the output, this is an alternative they might not have thought of

Comment: A df of lists is never a good idea if can be avoided. Performance drops one large dataframes even with the simplest operations

Comment: tbh it should probably be a dictionary. A df doesn't make a lot of sense either way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach

```
df.groupby('count')['num'].agg(list).apply(pd.Series).T
```